# Matrices in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, matrix

Is there any class for Matrix support in Objective-C? By Matrix I mean 2D-arrays.

What I do now is using 2 `NSArray`s, one within the other. This works perfectly but my code looks like a big mess.

I have also tried to use C-style arrays within each-other (`matrix[][]`) but this approach doesn't fit my application as I cannot automatically `@synthesize` or specify `@properties` for them.

I could of course create my own class for that, but what I'm wondering is if Objective-C already has something for this kind of situations. I did some Google-research but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, Foundation doesn't have any 2D array class. As far as mathematical computations are concerned, Matrices are typically implemented in C or C++ for portability and performance reasons. You'll have to write your own class for that if you really want it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems obj-c has not its own struct for matrix. I refered to the iOS SDK's CATransform3D, found that it use:

```
struct CATransform3D
{
    CGFloat m11, m12, m13, m14;
    CGFloat m21, m22, m23, m24;
    CGFloat m31, m32, m33, m34;
    CGFloat m41, m42, m43, m44;
};

typedef struct CATransform3D CATransform3D;
```

as the 3D transform matrix.

Comment: My goal was to access it using coordinates, let's say x and y. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I'd like to mention [this project](https://github.com/yconst/YCMatrix), which implements a flexible Matrix class based on a C array, with interfaces to many BLAS and LAPACK functions. *Disclaimer: I am the developer.*

Basic use is as follows:

```
YCMatrix *I = [YCMatrix identityOfRows:3 Columns:3];
double v = [I getValueAtRow:1 Column:1];
[I setValue:0 Row:0 Column:0];
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you will need to subclass NSArray or use some non-sweet syntax : [`MyArray objectAtIndex:i*d+j]`.  The latter case is really cumbersome as you will get only one clumsy kind of enumerator.

Comment: You should only subclass `NSArray` when you can provide your own storage.